# Jquery - target multiple child divs individually not simultaneously

Tags: jquery, html, target, children

I have a div that has multiple looping videos. In order to improve performance i have the videos paused until they scroll into the viewport using this code:

```
 jQuery(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){
        if (jQuery('#vid-container').visible(true)) {
               start_vid(); 
        } else {
            jQuery('iframe[id*="fitvid0"]').each(function () {
                 $f(this).api('pause');
            });
        }
    });
});

function start_vid(){
    jQuery('iframe[id*="fitvid0"]').each(function () {
                $f(this).api('setVolume', 0);
                $f(this).api('play');
            });
}
```

This works but since each video iframe has the same ID they all start playing at the same time once **#vid-container** comes into view.

Im trying to figure out a way that I could target each vid Iframe **individually** so they would begin playing one by one as the scroll into view **not simultaneously**.

something like:

```
if (jQuery('#vid-container child2, #vid-container child3, #vid-container child4, #vid-container child5').visible(true)) {
start_vid();
}
```

Hope that makes sense.. thanks

ps im using jquery.visible plugin and vimeo api

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you can't have the same ID on each video iframe.

Comment: The selector `$("#vid-container")` will only match the first element with that ID, not all of them. The reason it starts playing all of them is because the loop in `start_vid()` starts them all, not just the ones that are visible.

Comment: Thats the problem im trying to work around. The IDs are being generated by a wordpress plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check visibility in the `start_vid()` function.

```
function start_vid(){
    $f('iframe[id*="fitvid0"]').each(function () {
        if ($f(this).visible(true)) {
            $f(this).api('setVolume', 0);
            $f(this).api('play');
        }
    });
}
```